# wordpress threaded comments - customize nested ul / how child ul is displayd

Tags: comments

I just wasted 1 day trying to make wp threaded comments works... and I think I'm finally done!!!! except that it doesn't work properly - well it doesn't work the way I want ! :)

Child comments get displayed inside the comment li - I don't like this behavior, I'd prefer wp to display it right below the parent comment li.

```
So by default wp handles it like this:
<li id="commend-1">
comments parent here here
<ul id="child">
<li>child comment reply :P</li>
</ul>
</li>

Anyways, I want it displayed like this:
<li id="comment-1">
</li>
<li id="comment-2" class="isreply">
</li>
```

Is this possible without modifying core wp files? Did wp developers leave options that enable customization of how child/nested comments are displayed?

I'm including screen shot for better visual.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PiJu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a custom `Walker`. You will probably use `wp_list_comments()` somewhere in your `comments.php` template file. There you can pass a `walker` parameter in the argument array to tell WordPress you want to style the list on your own.

This requires you to extend the `Walker` class. The following resources should give you some examples.

1. Read the codex about the [Walker_Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class)
2. Check the sourcecode of the base class in `wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php` or the extending `Walker_Comment` class in `wp-includes/comment-template.php` on line `1218`.

Comment: thx, I think I found a great example of doing this:
http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/04/05/wordpress-get-your-own-markup-for-nested-comments/

I just need to understand it and implement :D

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Discussion and disable threaded comments.

Comment: that's a good one :) I want to use threaded comments, but customize it... disabling it won't help situation :P

Comment: You could use jquery to move all nested comment underneath their parent li.